# Detect whether user's location is within particular city with Google Maps SDK on iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps

I'm developing a navigation app for iOS using Google Maps SDK. I need to give a route search functionality only within one city, otherwise show a warning message.

So, the question is: can someone please recommend me a way to detect whether a user is within a particular city?

Great thanks in advance.

Comment: check if start and end position are in the same city. use reverse geocoding to get that info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find out user's current latitude and longitude.
In a google map you can plot a position with lat and long, and if its true for your city's coordinates - You are on.

A great documentation is [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/releases).